# mouseover is not working in jquery in my code

Tags: jquery, html

my following code works great but if I remove[0] from jquery code than it not works while it should be work.
and another question is that if I write mouseover instead of onmouseover than its also not work why...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>    <html>    <head>    <title>DOM Level 0 Events Example</title>    </head>

<body>

     <img id="example" src="footer.png" alt="ooooh! ahhhh!"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
$('#example')[0].onmouseover = function(event) {
alert('Crackle!');
};
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not a case of simply replacing `onmouseover` with `mouseover`. One is a property that needs a function assigned to it, the other is a method that has a function passed to it. Read the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is wrong.

`$('#example')[0].onmouseover` onmouseover won't work for jquery variable.

use `$('#example').on("mouseover", function(){});` instead.

or

`$('#example').mouseover(function(){ });`

without `[0]` because ID is **unique**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing there, but did you read the documentation?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

It's done like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#example" ).mouseover(function() {

        alert("Crackle!");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get rid of that [0]. You are using an ID as selector. So there can not be more than one ID. What you are doing is accessing the first element of a nodeList. Which is not possible in this case.

And you are missing $(document).ready() method.

Correct syntax should be

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$( "#example" ).mouseover(function(e) {
alert("Crackle!");
});
});
```

Comment: there is no need to write $(document).ready()  because I use the shortcut of this and your suggesion is right for ID but  this is the example of jquery book of "Action" so I use it ...thanks for advice